# if the input tag find alert the length , not found append the input tag

Tags: jquery

```
var $c = <fieldset id="asd"/> 
a=$c.append('<input type="hidden" id="sds"value="aa"/> ');
sdsds=$('fieldset').filter('#sds');
if(c.find('input'))
{
alert($('input').length)
}
else{
$c.append('<input type="hidden" id="sds"value="aa"/> ');
}
```

Im trying this
 if the input tag find alert the length , not found append the input tag

Comment: `if (c.find('input').length)`

Comment: u append input on $c but where you append $c

Comment: Im dnamically added the $c some have input tag and some have no input tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($c.find('input').length)
{
    alert($('input').length);
}
else{
    $c.append('<input type="hidden" id="sds"value="aa"/>');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MkDpU/

Comment: can i find with $c.find('input.class')length..i have unique classes

Comment: i find this but i need to find exact specific class

Comment: $c.find('input#sds').length

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use $c instead of c in the if clause.

```
if ($c.find('input')){
  alert($('input').length)
} else {
  $c.append('<input type="hidden" id="sds"value="aa"/> ');
}
```

But Why are you assigning a variable to the DOM manipulation? It does not look good.
$c should be appended somewhere.

```
a = $c.append('<input type="hidden" id="sds"value="aa"/> ');
```

Comment: i find this but i need to find exact specific id$c.find('input#sds').length